# codeigniter redirect doesn't work in the _construct method

Tags: php, codeigniter

i want to give access only to the authorized  users
so i wrote the authentication code in the construct method 
here is my code

```
class cp extends CI_Controller {

    public function __construct(){
        parent::__construct();
        $this->this_mustbe_admin();
    }

    public function this_mustbe_admin()
    {

        $this->load->model('m_cp');
        $md = $this->m_cp->is_admin();
        if($md)
         return $md;
        else
        {
            redirect(base_url().'cp/login/');
        }

    }

    function login()
    {   
             $this->load->view('admin/login');

    }
```

but i get error

```
The page isn't redirecting properly
```

if i remove `this_mustbe_admin` method from construct and put it on the other controllers it works fine

```
function do_stuff(){

   $this->this_mustbe_admin();
   // do stuff 

}
```

but this way i have to write it in each and every one of my methods

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You doing circular redirection. An imaginary stack trace:

1. http request to `/cp/`
2. `__construct()`
3. `this->this_mustbe_admin()` -> redirect to /cp/login
4. http request to `/cp/login`
5. `__construct()`
6. `this->this_mustbe_admin()` -> **GOTO 3.**

You will have to check what method you are trying to execute in your `__construct` before doing the redirection generating command.

```
if (!$this->router->method != 'login') {
    $this->this_mustbe_admin();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to write like this

```
redirect('base_url(cp/login)');
```

i hope may it wrks....or simply give

```
redirect('cp/login');
```

because i got when i used like this